# Can't run TestNG Test Suite in a maven project

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to execute a profile with mvn -PProfileName
But i'm getting errors, it seems that my pom.xml is correct and testngsuite.xml is correct too.
I can execute my code from the .java without any problem

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bilog</groupId>
    <artifactId>IncidentDashboardAutomation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>IncidentDashboardAutomation</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.40.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.paulhammant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ngwebdriver</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>RegressionTest</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>regression.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>Theriaque</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>theriaque.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

**regression.xml**

```
<suite name="IncidentDashboardSuite">
    <test name="Incident Dashboard Templae" preserve-order="true">
        <class name="com.bilog.IncidentDashboardAutomation.IncidentDashboardMainTestSuite.java">
        </class>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Errors I'm getting in eclipse console :**

```
[TestNGContentHandler] [WARN] It is strongly recommended to add "<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >" at the top of your file, otherwise TestNG may fail or not work as expected.
org.testng.TestNGException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:325)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:90)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:206)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:177)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.endElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:722)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:305)
    ... 3 more
```

**Errors i'm getting after mvn test-PRegressionTest**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.584 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-08-04T14:12:31+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project IncidentDashboardAutomation: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:325)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:281)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.endElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:722)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1783)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2970)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:118)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
[ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
[ERROR] at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
[ERROR] at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:305)
[ERROR] ... 7 more
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

PS : when I write mvn test -PRegressionTest,I get : Unknown lifecycle phase "test-PRegressionTest"

Thanks !

Comment: I would also recommend adding a `<scope>test</scope>` to your pom's  TestNG dependency declaration, as you don't want it to be identified as a transitive dependency of your packaged jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're missing the `<classes>` element in your TestNG config file. Try using this for your `regression.xml` file...

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="IncidentDashboardSuite">
    <test name="Incident Dashboard Templae" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.bilog.IncidentDashboardAutomation.IncidentDashboardMainTestSuite.java"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: @Hamza Amami - Did this solve your problem? If not, please let us know...if so, would you mind accepting the answer by clicking the green checkmark? It would be greatly appreciated either way =)